# Plotting After Merge

Tags: python-3.x, plot, merge

I have the following 'data' dataset:

[image]

This is just a sample. In reality I have 300 participants, 50 exercises, 6 areas, and level ranges from -4 to 4.

I then have the following 'area' dataset:

[image]

As you can see, in 'data' dataset, areas are reported using their 'area labels' rather than their 'description'

I would like to find a way to print in the 'data' dataset the words contained in 'description' column of 'area' dataset in place of the acronyms contained in 'area label' column

Ex. of result:
[image]

I have tried with the following code:

```
data.merge(area, left_on="area", right_on="arealabel").drop(columns=["arealabel","area"]).rename(columns={"description":"area"})
```

The system does NOT give me an error, but when I plot, the 'arealabels' are printed rather than their 'description'

Do you know how I can get the system to print 'description' rather than 'arealabel' in my plots?

Answer (score 0):

While not obvious from your question, I am assuming your datasets are in the form of Pandas DataFrames similar to the following:

```
df1 =   participant exercise    area    level
      0   3           DI         AGI      3
      1   3           DI         BAL      0
      2   3           LU         STR      4
      3   7           LU         AGI      2
      4   7           Ca         BAL      5
      5   21          Ro         POW      3
      6   21          Be         END      4  

df2 =             description
     arealabel  
       AGI        Agility
       BAL        Balance
       END        Endurance
       POW        Power
       RES        Resistance
       STR        Strength
```

Simply Reassign the contents of df1.area to the description value of df2 corresponding to the value of df1.area like the following:

```
for i in df1.index:
    df1.at[i, "area"] = df2.loc[df1.at[i, "area"]]['description']
```

This will update df1 to:

```
    participant exercise    area    level
0   3   DI  Agility 3
1   3   DI  Balance 0
2   3   LU  Strength    4
3   7   LU  Agility 2
4   7   Ca  Balance 5
5   21  Ro  Power   3
6   21  Be  Endurance   4
```

Now when you plot your data, the Area will reflect the description value.